# cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I  am fetching data from API and trying to convert it into deserialized form. But gettting this error.

```
public static async Task<List<Movie>> GetAllMovies(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Preferences.Get("accessToken", string.Empty));
            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + String.Format("api/movies/AllMovies?sort=asc&pageNumber={0}&pageSize={1}",pageNumber,pageSize));
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(response);

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use await before response

```
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(await response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to :

```
public static async Task<List<Movie>> GetAllMovies(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Preferences.Get("accessToken", string.Empty));
    var result = httpClient.GetStringAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + String.Format("api/movies/AllMovies?sort=asc&pageNumber={0}&pageSize={1}",pageNumber,pageSize));
    var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(response);
}
```